# Ruby on Rails : Autotest-notification on Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails, notifications, ubuntu-10.04, autotest

So after spending some time googling I finally got autotest to work on ubuntu with [autotest-notification](https://github.com/carlosbrando/autotest-notification)

It is working fine too. Just got a minor issue.

When I get an error the graphical notification pops up with the RED code . Then if I go fic the errors , the notification should turn green, but it doesn't. It continues to show the RED message.But the process in the terminal shows the correct result, it's just the graphical notification.

For example :[image: success in terminal] This is the success message in terminal.

[image: success in notification]
This is success message in notification.
Then I commit a mistake.
[image: fail error]
The notification is 
[image: fail notification]
Then I fix the errors and : 
[image: fixed]
[image: failed]
The FAIL notification continues to show up.

Once again all the code I use is from [here](https://github.com/carlosbrando/autotest-notification)
I followed [these steps](http://fredschoeneman.posterous.com/pimp-your-autotest-notification).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anyways I have managed to fix it somehow

```
$ sudo gem uninstall ZenTest
```

And then

```
$ sudo gem install autotest-notification
$ an-install
```

seems to do the trick. So I basically uninstalled zentest and installed autotest-notification agian and it works fine now.